# How to log the ASP pages requested during a particular time span?

Tags: performance, iis7, web-applications, cpu

I have a web application build in ASP and is hosted on IIS7 windows server 2008. Each day CPU level increases and the application stops responding (ASP pages don't load for ever, however an HTML page can be loaded at the same time, same Application pool without a problem.)  Then have to restart the Application pool.

I want to find out which specific pages are requested which made the CPU level go that high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on time-taken column in your site logs if it's not.
[Log Fields Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754702%28WS.10%29.aspx)
And query requests using [MS Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659)
e.g.(action tooks more than 3 seconds)

```
logparser.exe "SELECT cs-uri-stem AS turtle_requests FROM <yoursite.dtd> Where time-taken > 3000" -o:DATAGRID
```

You can query grouping, counting etc.
[Some Sample Queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/microsoft-logparser.html)